# Python - No module named

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code with few modules:

```
import Persistence.Image as img
import sys

def main():
    print(sys.path)
    original_image = img.Image.open_image()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

(I've created my own Image module)

And so I'm getting the following error claiming that the Persistence module does not exist:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ulises/PycharmProjects/IntelligentPuzzle/Puzzle.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Persistence.Image as img
ImportError: No module named Persistence.Image
```

I've been searching for this problem here but can't find anything that worked to solve this as the directory tree seems to be correct as you can see on this image:

[image]

I'm using ubuntu if it's any use.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: does your persistance folder have and `__init__.py` file that loads `Image` into the local namespace?

Comment: Are you adding `/home/ulises/PycharmProjects/IntelligentPuzzle` to the python path?  You can't import Persistence if the directory above it is not in the python path.

Comment: @Aaron yeah that worked!! Sorry I'm just starting and didn't know about that file and was deleting it lol.

Comment: @Wrong [here's](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/#packages) a quick few paragraphs on python packages from [The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/) to maybe give you a better idea of what's going on with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Persistence` package does not exist in that source tree. There is a *"Persistence"* directory there, but it is not a package, because it does not contain a `__init__.py` file.

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that you are importing with proper syntax.  You need to use `from Persistance import Image as img`.  For example:

```
>>> import cmath.sqrt as c_sqrt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cmath.sqrt
ImportError: No module named 'cmath.sqrt'; 'cmath' is not a package
>>> from cmath import sqrt as c_sqrt
>>> c_sqrt(-1)
1j
```

Comment: `import cmath.sqrt` fails because `sqrt` is a function, so it cannot be imported. In the question, `Image` is a module, so the syntax would be valid if `Persistance` was a package. It fails because `import Persistance` fails. Try e.g. `import os.path as ospath`.